# gulp.src using sync globbing

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, glob

I looked at the source for `gulp.src()`, and apparently it's just a reference to `require('vinyl-fs').src()`. Looking at the documentation for vfs's `src()`, it says that it takes any options that it defines, along "any glob-related options are documented in glob-stream and node-glob." According to `node-glob`'s documentation, I can pass in the options `{ sync: true }`.

When I try to use `gulp.src(..., { sync: true })`, however, I get this error from gulp:

```
TypeError: Object #<GlobSync> has no method 'on'
```

Any idea how to specify `sync` option with `gulp.src()`?

Comment: You can't :). Could you elaborate why you need that?

Comment: A guess: is it for sorting the results?

Comment: This issue is that I run a `gulp.src().pipe(concat())`, and since I'm passing in globbing patterns into `gulp.src()`, and matches are returned async, the order of the `concat()` output keeps changing. If glob-matching is async by default, I don't understand how anyone can rely on `concat()` concatenating in the same order every time. On my machine, `glob` returns the files it finds in different order all the time, so `concat()` will not *always* concat in the same order. How is this not a *huge* issue for everyone using gulp? Does that explanation make any sense? :)

Comment: Yes, it does and I was sort of expecting that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still ran into problems using `gulp.src(filePatterns).pipe(order(filePatterns))`. The concatenated output order now stays the same everytime I run `gulp`, but the order of concatenation isn't in the order specified by the `filePatterns` array literal. Maybe I'm missing something.

Whatever the case, I ended up implementing this workaround below. Instead of doing, for example, `gulp.src(filePatterns)`, I now do `gulp.src(deglob(filePatterns))` and get the same order each time, and in the order that the `filePatterns` array literal is defined.

```
function deglob() {
    var syncGlob = require('glob').sync,
        patterns = _.flatten(arguments, true);

    return _.flatten(patterns.map(function(pattern) {
        return syncGlob(pattern).map(function(file) {
            return pattern.charAt(0) === '!' ? ('!' + file) : file;
        });
    }), true);
}
```

I've actually stopped using `gulp.src()` completely and instead use this everywhere:

```
gulp.from = function () {
    return gulp.src(deglob(arguments));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need files to be in certain order use either [gulp-sort](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sort) (alphabetical etc.) or [gulp-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order) (globs).

For background info see this issue: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/687

Comment: This means I now have to (correct?) do this: `gulp.src(filePatterns).pipe(order(filePatterns))` to get the same order each time.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following solution, I apply `gulp.src` with [gulp-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order) on each glob individually and use [merge2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge2) to sequentially merge the streams.

```
var order = require('gulp-order');
var merge = require('merge2');    

var paths = ['folder1/**/*', 'folder2/**/*'];

var streams = paths.map(function (path) {
    return gulp.src(path)
        .pipe(order([path]));
});

return merge.apply(this, streams);
```

This way, `order()` makes sure that each individual glob is sorted in a fixed (alphabetical) order, and merge concatenates the streams.

Downside: the paths must be disjoint, and negations are not possible.

In order to allow for overlapping, the script could be modified in the following way to add the other path(s) as negations. This also allows for negations.

```
var paths = [['src/**/*.module.js'], ['src/**/*.js', '!src/**/*.module.js']];

var streams = paths.map(function (path) {
    return gulp.src(path)
        .pipe(order(path));
});

return merge.apply(this, streams);
```